# Mobile is not detected by Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile, connection, usb, adb

I am running the Android Studio Flamingo version. My Samsung M32 is attached for debugging the application, but it is not detected by the Android Studio. While running the "troubleshoot device connection" it gives an error: "Android Studio detected 16 device(s).
Found 2 Android device(s) with possible problems:
RZ8RC1N3A7V

- Device was detected by ADB but not Android Studio, emulator-5554
- Device was detected by ADB but not Android Studio."

It was previously detected, but not now. Moible and its data is visible on Widonw File Explorer.

I have restarted by mobile.
May any one provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

On the device, try going to Settings | Developer Options and disable then enable USB Debugging.  I can't remember if I did this while the device was connected via USB, so try connected and disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Also check (on the phone): Settings > Developer Options > Default USB Configuration = File Transfer.

Sometimes it defaults to "No Data Transfer" and that would also prevent your device from being seen.